# How to get the first non-whitespace char column number by vimscript

Tags: vim, neovim

In buffer has this line with a text,how can i get the column number of char `s` in vimscript, the `80:` mean line number.

```
80:                  some text
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between "column" and "virtual column" (e.g. after "tab")? Which one you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, if it gives what you are looking for:

```
match(getline('X'),'\S')
```

**Note** replace the `X` with the line number you want to search. E.g. `'80'` for your example.